# Integrating Limit Switches with ROS2, Moveit2, and Dynamixel Motors for Robot "Homing" Sequence

Tags: ros2, moveit, hardware-interface

Hello ROS2 and Moveit2 community,

I am working on a robotics project where I need to effectively integrate limit switches into the robot initialization process. The main challenge is implementing a "homing" sequence for a robot using ROS2, Moveit2, and Dynamixel servo motors (with relative encoders) in extended position control mode.

**Key Objective:**

Execute a homing sequence between each target location selected by the user and ideally maintain the robot model without frequent reboots.

**Current Setup:**

1. Dynamixel servo motors (with relative encoders).
2. Integrated limit switches in the robot.
3. Ability to move the robot using joint trajectory controller and stop at limit switches.
4. Ubuntu 22.04; ros2 Humble; moveit2

**Problem:**
After a reboot, the relative encoder output of the Dynamixel motors becomes unreliable. I can calculate the offset between the starting encoder value and the value at the limit switch, but I'm uncertain about the best way to utilize this offset.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. **Utilizing Dynamixel 'Homing Offset' Parameter:**

Run the homing sequence before starting the ros_controller.
Adjust the 'homing offset' hardware parameter.
**Concern:** How would I adjust this parameter between each user-selected point and run the homing sequence with moveit2 running??

2. **Calculate offset for each mimic joint.**

I have mimic joints for each joint in my robot to account for gear reductions and prismatic joints. I could update the offset for each of these mimic joints during runtime. **Concern:** How to update mimic joint offsets with ROS2 and Moveit2 already running? Would this approach be considered good practice?

3. **Manually apply the offset prior to motion plan**

I could implement something that stores these parameters and then applies them before the motion plan request is sent. **Concern:** I don't know how I would update the robot in rviz to reflect the calculated offsets. Maybe I can set up my own planning scene and apply these offsets to the robot state prior to display? Just not sure if that is possible.

I am seeking advice on the best approach to integrate these limit switches for homing. Any insights on managing the homing sequence would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

Comment: It might help to post your URDF and mention the Dynamixel model you are using. I personally have not seen a Dynamixel servo that has only relative encoder, they usually have both relative and absolute. I have to assume you have your "Hardware" node implemented, and it's derived from Robot_HW? In that case I would start off all the joints at either min or max, and then have MoveIt drive them toward the other end as a final step in your startup sequence. When the limit is hit, your hardware node could then know if you hit min or max, and reset joint states it's reporting to that value.